# React Router get which `<NavLink />` is active?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I render some `<NavLink />` like below

```
<div class="container">
  <NavLink to="/" exact></NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/profile"></NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/message"></NavLink>
</div>
```

it's cool that react-router will add an `active` class to which is currently matched.

but how do I know which one is currently active ?

because I have some other styles to adjust based on this, like when in `'/'` I want to give `.container` 100px padding-left, and when in '/profile', I want to give `.container` 200px padding-left.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different activeClassName to each of them.

(See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink)

For example

```
<div class="container">
<NavLink to="/" exact></NavLink>
<NavLink to="/profile" activeClassName="matched-profile"></NavLink>
<NavLink to="/message"></NavLink>
</div>
```

Then style container like this `.container:has(.matched-profile)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use withRouter to get the path of the current page, by using pathname you can file which is your current page.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Location extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

const WithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```